# "happen to be" and "happen to have" - expressions of probability?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Based on Logman dictionary:

> **happen to do something**: if you happen to do something, you do it by chance.

for example take a look at these examples:

- They happen to be unemployed at the time.
- I happen to have a degree in computer science.

So based on the definition of the **happen to do something**, first one means they are probably unemployed at the time. and the second one means I probably have a degree in computer science.

Am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Happen" does come from the Middle English word "hap," meaning luck or chance, and it does retain that connotation in situations where it means occurs by chance:

> I just **happened** to meet my cousin at the concert.

We didn't plan to go to the same concert.  It was just a chance meeting.

But "happen" also simply means occurs:

> The scandal is called "Watergate" because that's the name of the building where the break-in
>   **happened**.

No chance involved:  the break-in was deliberate.

Sometimes the word is employed for things that themselves didn't come about randomly but are relevant to the conversation only by chance:

> A: My program isn't working.  I wish someone could help.
>  B: Let
>   me take a look.  I **happen** to have a degree in computer science.

Here B is saying that he has a degree in computer science, and this is something that doesn't come about by chance but by planned study.  What is a chance happening is that A needs help and has run into someone who can help.

In all these cases (and in your examples as well), these are statements of fact and not probability.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all.  In both cases, something "happened". It is a fact, not just a possibility.

To say "happened to be" or "happened to have" implies that it could have happened *by chance* (not likely for a degree in computer science—that would necessarily be *intentional*).

It does not include an iota of chance that the thing might NOT have happened.