# Is “happen” stative or dynamic

Tags: verbs, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

The progressive tense is allowed for *happen*, e.g. "It is happening now". Thus *happen* should be a dynamic verb. However, it seems that *happen* also looks like a stative verb sometimes, e.g. "I happen to be there". I want to make sure if *happen* is a stative or dynamic verb or both.

**Note**: This question is very different from the question suggested to be the duplicate because I ask in this question whether *happen* is a stative or dynamic verb or both, which is not answered in another one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["happen to be" and "happen to have" - expressions of probability?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272620/happen-to-be-and-happen-to-have-expressions-of-probability)_, where the different senses and usages of 'happen' are explained in deadrat's answer. In 'A disaster was bound to happen', 'happen' = 'occur'. But 'I happen to have a Tiger tank round the corner', 'I happen to have ...' is a fixed expression meaning 'The actual situation (and you're going to love this) is that I have ...'. The 'occur' sense, like 'occur', is dynamic.

Comment: `happening` in that first sentence is a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiU3o7A393lAhUlFjQIHZgXCGQQwqsBMAB6BAgJEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOZ3DKv6ft_0&usg=AOvVaw2YEc7_wHpWmVSrCr2Tapgo

Comment: That which 'haps' is a state. A state of change may be happening, but what exists is a state : a condition of change. Without any changes whatsoever, time is not measurable and does not actually exist. When anything 'happens' it indicates that there is a change of state occurring and time is measurable. 'Happen' is both static and dynamic simultaneously.

Comment: @MathWizard My answer is somewhat conceptual rather than linguistic, which is why I made it a comment rather than an answer. Good question (+1).

Comment: I already noted in the post that this is not the duplicate